# Getting an array from a SOAP server in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, soap

first things first. Im a n00b. I'm starting to do things in PHP, getting the basics and all. Anyway i need to do this, although im aware it's not within my current knowledge.

I've managed to interact with a SOAP server sending data in the form of an object, and receive a single string or things like this. But i can't receive an Array...

Here's my code.

```
class cUSER {
        public $LOGIN;
        public $PASS;
}

$pcUser = new cUSER;
$pcUser->LOGIN = "user"; 
$pcUser->PASS  = "pass";

try {
    $client = new SoapClient("http://servername.es:8200/SOAPSERV.asmx?wsdl", array(‘features’ => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));

    //var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
    $cACCESORIO =  $client->GET_ACCESORIOS($pcUser);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    die();

}
```

And here is the specifications i received from the server developer:

> **GET_ACCESORIOS** Need a User objec as param. Gives back an array of the object. Gives back an object:
>
> **REFERENCIA** (model id)
>   **MODELO** (model name)
>   **PVP** (price)
>   **HasError** (Shows if an error has ocurred)
>   **ERROR** (error description)

**SERVER REPLY IS:**

> Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.

I've tried several things, help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, the server documentation was wrong. and since i'm a noob i accepted the error was on my side. It seems like the server developer is id**t.

thanks anyway